# Setting a value to a class variable and putting it into an array changes value of previous additions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an app that pulls an XML file from the server, stores it, then parses it to form a `UIListView`. The names of blog posts are stored in the XML file, along with other info. To work with the data, I wrote two classes, `Post` (which stores the name, link, content, etc. of the blog posts) and `PostList` (which stores an `NSMutableArray` of all the `Post` objects, along with other info).

I'm encountering a problem where, in the loop below, (part of the `getPosts` method in my `PostList` class) whenever the `aPost` variable is modified, it changes the value of all of the stored values of `aPost` from previous loop iterations.

I don't understand why that's happening. Can anyone explain?

```
TBXMLElement *element = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *nextElement = element->nextSibling;
NSLog(@"URLs have been set, preparing for parse/input. [PostList.getPosts]");

//Extracts the content of the XML file and saves it to values in the Post Class
do {
    /**********
     * This loop goes through the XML file looking for <item> tags that hold information
     * about the blog posts. It finds <item> tags and scours them for <title>, <description>, 
     * <pubdate>, and <link> tags to put into the class variables for the Post Class (aPost).
     *********/

    NSString *stringElement = [TBXML elementName:element];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringElement);

    //Sorts through the header junk to find the first <item> tag.
    if (![stringElement isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        if (!(element->firstChild)) {
            if (!(element->nextSibling)) {
                element = nil;
            }
            element = element->nextSibling;
        }
        element = element->firstChild;
    }
    //Once the first <item> tag is found, this code executes.
    else {
        //Now we move to the first child tag and scour its contents and its siblings
        nextElement = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"item" searchFromElement:element];
        element = element->firstChild;
        do {
            //Here it loops over and over until all the parts have been collected.
            stringElement = [TBXML elementName:element];
            if ([stringElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
                aPost.name = [TBXML textForElement:element];
            }
            if ([stringElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
                aPost.content = [TBXML textForElement:element];
            }
            if ([stringElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
                aPost.postURL = [TBXML textForElement:element];
            }
            if ([stringElement isEqualToString:@"pubdate"]) {
                aPost.publicationDate = [TBXML textForElement:element];
            }
            element = element->nextSibling;
        } while (element->nextSibling);
        NSLog(@"%@", [self getName:self.aPost]);
        [self.postsArray insertObject:aPost atIndex:countingIndex];
        countingIndex++;
        element = nextElement;

    }
} while ((element != nil));
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining aPost as a property in your header file, just define it directly after entering the do part of the loop, e. g. like:

```
...
else {
    //Now we move to the first child tag and scour its contents and its siblings
    nextElement = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"item" searchFromElement:element];
    element = element->firstChild;
    do {
        Post* aPost = [[Post alloc] init]; // <-- create a new post, don't reuse or class level pointer
        //Here it loops over and over until all the parts have been collected.
        stringElement = [TBXML elementName:element];
```

... and also remove the Post property in the header file.

Comment: You guys rock so much! Thanks :) I almost feel embarrassed, it was such an easy fix...

Comment: Happy that you got it running. Have fun in ObjC land ;-)

Comment: @SonictheRocketman: If you recieve an answer here that solves your problem definitively, please take a second to [give it the "accepted" checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/159251). This rewards the answerer and helps future readers when they have a similar problem. You'll also get a small reputation reward yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new Post element in each iteration of the look, otherwise all entries in the array will reference the same object, which you update values to.

```
do {
    //...
    if (...) {
    } else {
        //...
        aPost = [[Post alloc] init];
        do {
            //...
        } while(...)
        //...
    }
    //...
} while(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been staring at that block of code for 6 hours fixing various things and rewriting it for the umpteen-bilionth time! You are a lifesaver! MY FIRST APP WORKS!